# How to find a sequence of any character followed by a certain number in bash

Tags: bash

So I have a for loop in Bash,
where I find all filenames that contain "_$i".

```
for ((i=1; i<=10; i++)); do
  string=$(find . -name "*_$i*")
  # do something with string
done
```

How can I change the above code to find filenames that contain any single arbitrary character (not just an underscore) followed by $i?

Comment: Do you really want to find files with a `10` like `match_one_and10.txt` twice ? And not match a `filewithonly0.txt`

Comment: Can you skip the loop with `find . -name "*?[1-9]*"` ?

Comment: @WalterA yes I could do that, thanks for the suggestion, but it does not apply to my particular use-case. Surprisingly, I actually want to find files with `10` twice and not find 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The glob pattern syntax for matching a single arbitrary character is `?`:

```
find . -name "*?$i*"
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a syntax for any single arbitrary character that isn't a number?

Comment: You can invert a character range: `[!0-9]`